# semantic logging work in Windows 8/8.1

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-store

We are looking for Logging application block for our windows store application. When i see 
http://pnp.azurewebsites.net/en-us/ website, they mention semantic logging work in Windows 8/8.1?. But there is no solid statement of support for windows store. has any one started using Semantic Logging Application Block in their windows store Application, please let us know. Is it advisable to use SLAB in windows store apps.

Answer (score 1):

The currently released version doesn't support Windows Store apps (see [System Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn169621.aspx#sec6)). It's on our [backlog](https://slab.codeplex.com/workitem/9). Feel free to vote and comment with the details of the scenarios you care about.